# Why does max-height break border-radius?

Tags: html, css

I have an inline svg with the following css code:

```
.img {
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 70vw;
    margin-top: 6vh;
    max-height: 50vh;
    z-index: -1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And it all works as expected, except for border radius. When the screen shrinks to a certain width (837px), it works fine, but before that it doesn't do anything. The issue seems to be max height, because when I remove that property the border radius works at all sizes. Is there any way to fix this? Any help would be much appreciated, if you need me to upload anything else (svg code, or html) just let me know. Thanks in advance.

Edit:
As per request, I am including full HTML+CSS.

https://codepen.io/Angersmash/pen/xxgVMgP

Comment: Please could you put up a complete snippet which shows the problem and includes the SVG.

Comment: @A Haworth Codepen link is now in post.

Comment: edit your question and include your HTMl with css as stacksnippet (**Ctrl + M**). If the link or content of the codepen changes, this quzestion would hold no further value.

Comment: Sorry, but the code is too long - SO doesn't allow it.

Comment: Thanks. If you put border-style: solid on the image you can see the border is there, but the img is wide, which explains why you only start to see the rounding of the corners when the width is decreased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the width of the svg is larger than its height (although the basic house image is square) - the .img settings are set at max 70vw/50vh width/height respectively.

If you make the border solid you can see the problem clearly - the border is there, and with rounded corners, but it is width-wise away from the house.

[image]

If we set `max-width` of the .img to the same as the `max-height` then the border works and you get rounded corners. Below the snippet which does that, but the svg is too big for SO to handle so I've removed the rooms and here is what you get:

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>продастся!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Cyrillic';
    src: url('./DaysOne-Regular.ttf');
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


html, body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}



body {
    background: radial-gradient(74.83% 147.97% at 79.1% 76.51%, rgba(102, 255, 218, 0.39) 0%, rgba(50, 243, 255, 0.39) 100%);

}

header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 8vh;
    font-family: 'Cyrillic';
    color: rgba(193, 83, 83, 1);
}

header h3 {
    margin-top: 2vh;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3vh;
    font-family: 'Cyrillic';
    color: #339E8C;
}
.img {
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* max-width: 70vw; */
    max-width: 50vh;
    margin-top: 6vh;
    max-height: 50vh;
    z-index: -1;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    background: #599696;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    white-space: pre;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
}

.text {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 120%;
    transform: translateY(1.3vh);
    font-family: 'Cyrillic';
}

.img #bottomRoom:hover :not(.textWrapBottom) {
    filter: brightness(0.8);
}

.img #kitchen:hover :not(.kitchenText) {
    filter: brightness(0.7);
}

.img #upstairsFull:hover {
    filter: brightness(0.7);
}

.img #topRightRoom:hover {
    filter: brightness(0.7);
}

.img #topLeftRoom:hover {
    filter: brightness(0.7);
}

.img #bathroom:hover {
    filter: brightness(0.7);
}

.img  text {
    visibility: hidden;
    fill: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Cyrillic';
}



    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>продастся!</h1>
        <h3>Добро пожаловать в твой новый дом!</h3>
    </header>
    <div class="image" style="text-align: center;">
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
        <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
        <svg width="100%" class="img" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 500" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2;">
            <g id="img">
                <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" style="fill:rgb(74,192,211);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
                <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,2.67532)">
                    <rect x="0" y="408.876" width="500" height="91.124" style="fill:rgb(85,140,75);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
                </g>
                <rect x="0" y="376.883" width="93.535" height="2.868" style="fill:rgb(60,36,21);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
                <rect x="0" y="396.293" width="92.528" height="2.868" style="fill:rgb(60,36,21);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
                <rect x="25.681" y="366.504" width="6.247" height="42.768" style="fill:rgb(117,76,41);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
                <rect x="42.338" y="366.504" width="6.246" height="42.768" style="fill:rgb(117,76,41);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
                <rect x="58.994" y="366.504" width="6.247" height="42.768" style="fill:rgb(117,76,41);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
                <rect x="75.653" y="366.504" width="6.246" height="42.768" style="fill:rgb(117,76,41);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
                <rect x="9.022" y="366.504" width="6.247" height="42.768" style="fill:rgb(117,76,41);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
                <rect x="406.465" y="376.883" width="93.535" height="2.868" style="fill:rgb(60,36,21);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
                <rect x="407.472" y="396.293" width="92.528" height="2.868" style="fill:rgb(60,36,21);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
                <rect x="468.072" y="366.504" width="6.247" height="42.768" style="fill:rgb(117,76,41);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
                <rect x="451.416" y="366.504" width="6.246" height="42.768" style="fill:rgb(117,76,41);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
                <rect x="434.759" y="366.504" width="6.247" height="42.768" style="fill:rgb(117,76,41);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
                <rect x="418.101" y="366.504" width="6.246" height="42.768" style="fill:rgb(117,76,41);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
                <rect x="484.731" y="366.504" width="6.246" height="42.768" style="fill:rgb(117,76,41);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
</g>
        </svg>
        
     </div>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="text">звоните по - телефони:</div>
        telephone
        email
    </footer>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much - fixed my problem! You're amazing, have a great day!